# Vocabulary with int64 in LDA2Vec

Tags: python

sorry for my poor English..
I'm work with LDA2Vec by cemoody .. in preprocessing stage to get vocab using **(int64)**, but I have a problem with **negative numbers** can't deals with it and get this
**ERROR "Negative indices reserved for special tokens"**
AND, when I used (**uint64**) as:

```
 dat = doc.to_array([attr, LIKE_EMAIL, LIKE_URL]).astype('uint64')
    print(dat)
    if len(dat) > 0:
        msg = "Negative indices reserved for special tokens" 
        assert dat.min() >= 0, msg
        # Replace email and URL tokens
        # select the indices of tokens that are URLs or Emails
        idx = (dat[:, 1] > 0) | (dat[:, 2] > 0)
        dat = dat.astype('uint64')
        dat[idx] = skip
        length = min(len(dat), max_length)
        data[row, :length] = dat[:length, 0].ravel()
uniques = np.unique(data)
vocab = {v: nlp.vocab[v].lower_ for v in uniques if v != skip}
vocab[skip] = '<SKIP>'
return data, vocab
```

the result for **text=["cold","warm"]** is: **{3117178197819627377: 'cold', 4469020372817945905: 'warm', 18446744073709551614: ''}**

**but when** retrying to get string the key is **mismatching**

```
 keys = np.array(loose_counts)[:, 0]
```

**result: [1.84467441e+19 3.11717820e+18 4.46902037e+18]**
... therefore when try to get **string** for each key  return OoV.

can anyone halp me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve this problem by using different processes in tokenization

```
voc = Vocab()
if nlp is None:
    nlp = Arabic()
data = np.zeros((len(texts), max_length) , dtype='int32')

data[:] = skip

for row, doc in enumerate(nlp.pipe(texts, **kwargs)):
    s = str(doc)
  
    dat = voc.word2index(s.split(), train=True)
    if len(dat) > 0:
        dat = np.array(dat).astype('int32')
        #print(dat)
        msg = "Negative indices reserved for special tokens"
        assert dat.min() >= 0, msg
        length = min(len(dat), max_length)
   
        data[row ,:length] = dat[:length]  
    
uniques = np.unique(data)
vocab = {v: voc.index2word(v) for v in uniques if v != skip}
vocab[skip] = '<SKIP>'
return data, vocab
```